# Upload photo from firebase storage URL to facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, firebase, firebase-storage

My app should post a taken picture to facebook. The photo is stored to my firebase storage bucket. I´m getting the URL from this photo and pass that to facebook.

**The URL:**

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gettoworkout-50cd0.appspot.com/o/post%2F-Kbo3hZgL8DUqQv_vYZ2.jpg?alt=media&token=ce764afe-2f2e-4632-b978-f3f2cc65f9cc
```

**This is the Graph API I´m calling:**

```
me/photos?token=mytoken&caption=test&url=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gettoworkout-50cd0.appspot.com/o/post%2F-Kbo3hZgL8DUqQv_vYZ2.jpg?alt=media&token=ce764afe-2f2e-4632-b978-f3f2cc65f9cc&method=post
```

A normal file URL apart from firebase works fine. So my suggestion is, that facebook is not getting the file because of the `alt=media` and `token=token` attributes from firebase.

If I paste this URL to the browser, the image is downloaded not shown.

How to upload that image to Facebook?

Comment: _“How to bypass this?”_ – by applying proper URL-encoding to the value that you are _putting into a URL_, of course.

Comment: This URL is from the firebase getDownloadURL function. This is a valid URL scheme. But Facebook is not accepting it. An html img tag does accept it and shows the image correctly

Comment: I did not say the URL was not valid - what you are _doing_ with it (inserting it as a parameter value into another URL) is _wrong_, because you neglected to apply proper URL encoding to the parameter value.

Comment: You are right. But if I escape the ? (with %3F) and & (with %26) in the firebase URL it does not work either... The link stops working, too. Could you point me to the right direction how to encode the URL correctly?

Comment: You don’t encode single characters, you encode the whole value. And once you properly do that, it works perfectly fine: https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?token=mytoken&caption=test&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebasestorage.googleapis.com%2Fv0%2Fb%2Fgettoworkout-50cd0.appspot.com%2Fo%2Fpost%252F-Kbo3hZgL8DUqQv_vYZ2.jpg%3Falt%3Dmedia%26token%3Dce764afe-2f2e-4632-b978-f3f2cc65f9cc&method=post&access_token={add_access_token_here}

Comment: Awesome it works. I used JS encodeURI() function. If you would post this as answer, I´m accepting it. Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry guys, I did not understand m1crdy. I'm also working with JS (ionic2) and i'm trying to encodeURIComponent() the value of the parameter that points to the image in firebase storage. However it seems to fail. Any other info about how did you achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are putting one URL into another URL here, as a parameter value.

So you need to properly **URL-encode** the value - so that the “special characters” it contains that have a defined meaning in a URL are not ambiguous.

In PHP, `urlencode` would be the proper function to use; other languages should have similar functions or tools available for this.

Comment: Hi CBroe, I am getting exactly same thing on ANGULARJS.. I also encode firebase url with using encodeURIComponent .. But still same error.. Do you have any idea ? Thanks

Comment: @Ozi dunno, hard to tell without any code. Suggest you create a new question containing your specific code, and reference this one.